# Connecting two spring boot applications to respond to each other

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

My problem is the following: I want to be able to start one spring application from another. I have one application and other is microservice which should enable from time to time. How can I achieve this?

In the ideal scenario if application receive rest request from the other one, it should turn on, but I know its impossible since it can't communicate if it's not working.

Comment: 'microservice which should enable from time to time' - Did you try [serverless computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serverless_computing)?

Comment: No I haven't, I only heard that docker can automatically turn on your server when it shuts down.

Comment: this might be of interest: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a perfect use case for [serverless computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serverless_computing). But if really want to avoid that and want to start and stop pods in kubernetes cluster you can use the [kubernetes api](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/) from the primaty process.

Alternatively, you can start the secondary service in the same Docker container with [Runtime.exec()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("java -jar secondary.jar");
```

The primary process will need to listen for a call emanating from the secondary service to indicate the secondary service is up.

When secondary is known to be up, primary can make the call. Or it can simple keep retrying until a good response is received.

When the secondary has completed its work it will need to System.exit(). (Or can call primary to terminate it)